# Summability Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, cesaro-summable

Today I was reading Cesaro Summability and Abel summability. I found that there exists a series which is Cesaro summable but do not converge in conventional way (the usual way...). Again there exists a series which is Abel summable but not Cesaro summable.

> **My Question:** Is this type of summability has an end. *I mean* is there any rule, say $P$... after that you can not impose any other rule $Q$ such that we will *not* have the following: There exists a series which is $Q$ summable but not $P$ summable.

---

---

Btw is there any other summability which dominates Abel Summability?

Comment: Generally no.  Once you impose a rule on summability someone else can generalise or change one of your hypotheses to generate a new rule of summability.  An excellent reference is Hardy's Divergent Series (archive.org will let you view it here: https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries but if you can get hold of the AMS reissue it's a lovely book) which will give you just about every useful way to sum a series.

Comment: [Borel summations maybe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation)?

Comment: thanks @postmortes